# Setting Zend Framework path on Lion?

Tags: php, zend-framework, osx-lion

I'm trying to setup the Zend Framework on Lion, I installed "Zend" in

```
/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend
```

my PHP path is (`php -i | grep include_path`):

```
include_path => .: => .:
```

I tried to do:

```
<?php
    set_include_path('ZendFramework-1.10.3-minimal/library/'.get_include_path());
    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
    Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
?>
```

What I see in the browser is:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/ngoles/Programming/WWW/ApparelDream/appareldream/test.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='ZendFramework-1.10.3-minimal/library/.:') in /Users/ngoles/Programming/WWW/ApparelDream/appareldream/test.php on line 3
```

Advice on setting up the path correctly ?

Comment: Your autoload method is deprecated as of ZF 1.8. Use `require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a combination of the comment and answer I saw here.  Here is a simple example from [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/learning.autoloading.usage.html).

```
// the first two lines should set it up for the Zend library
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// these are for custom libraries, two different ways of doing it
// and NOT necessary if you don't have any custom libraries
$loader->registerNamespace('Foo_');
$loader->registerNamespace(array('Foo_', 'Bar_'));
```

This is what [Zend had to say about it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/learning.autoloading.usage.html):

> By default, this will allow loading any classes with the class namespace prefixes of "Zend_" or "ZendX_", as long as they are on your include_path.
>
> What happens if you have other namespace prefixes you wish to use? The best, and simplest, way is to call the registerNamespace() method on the instance. You can pass a single namespace prefix, or an array of them:

---

And then, of course, be sure to include the `PATH_SEPARATOR` when assigning *more than one* path using `set_include_path()`, otherwise it will just *concatenate* them.

Here is how I'd do it in my **index.php** file.

```
set_include_path(
    '/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/library' .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() .
    PATH_SEPARATOR . '.'
);
```